# How to upgrade Session Keys to OAuth Access Tokens Facebook?

Tags: facebook, session, oauth, key, upgrade

I novice with RestFB Java library. In fact, I don't understand very well how to get an OAuth access tokens ? Before I used Facebook Api Java with API key and Secret key for authentification. Now, I want to use RestFB to replace this library.

Can you help me please ? Have you got some Java example for this new mechanism ?

Thank you very much,

Regards,

Anthony

Answer (score 0):

Read this http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/

Understand how to do it with curl, then it should be very easy to implement in java using whatever java client you wish. Its probably a good idea for you to take the time to understand oauth and how it works, then try to implement it. I know it saved me a ton of time!

Answer (score 0):

Both of these app have fragments of OAuth code in filters/servlets but i've had trouble with both. They might give you some pointers

http://code.google.com/p/facebook-java-webapp/

http://code.google.com/p/checkflames/

http://jazzy.id.au/default/2008/03/19/facebook_authentication_in_java.html